# IMPALA date formats - Convert full timestamp to hourly timestamp

Tags: datetime, time, format, impala

I need to take a full timestamp column (Format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSSS`) and convert it into hourly timestamp   (Format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:00:00`)

For example:
I want to convert my existing date:

```
2016-02-26 04:00:07.766304000
```

into:

```
2016-02-26 04:00:00
```

I tried to use `unix_timestamp()` and `from_unixtime()`  function but it is too confusing :X

Does someone know how to easily do it?

Many Thanks for the helpers :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use to_date() to get the date of the time and hour() to get the hour of the time, and then concat them together if you do not want to use unix_timestamp() or from_unixtime().

Suppose 'submit_time' looks like '2016-02-26 04:00:07.766304000'.

```
concat(to_date(submit_time),' ',cast(hour(submit_time) as string),':00:00')
```

will gives the answer.